# Can I create 2 kernel in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-8

Currently, I'm managing my schedule command at the kernel.
Includes every minute running commands and scheduled commands.
Because scheduling processing in Laravel is sequential, scheduled commands can be delayed by commands running in minutes. I am planning to split the kernel into 2 parts to run in parallel. That's possible?
[image: first kernel]
[image: second kernel]

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and then add all relevant code and potential error messages as text instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want instead, is [chained jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/queues#job-chaining):

```php
use App\Jobs\OptimizePodcast;
use App\Jobs\ProcessPodcast;
use App\Jobs\ReleasePodcast;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus;
 
Bus::chain([
    new ProcessPodcast,
    new OptimizePodcast,
    new ReleasePodcast,
])->dispatch();
```

Another option is to schedule a subsequent job:

```php
$schedule
    ->command('your:first-command')
    ->cron('*/30 * * * *') // every 30 minutes
    ->then(function() {
        $this->call('your:second-command');
        $this->call('your:third-command');
        $this->call('your:fourth-command');
    })
;
```

Or you only call the first command in your console Kernel and dispatch subsequent commands at the end of their respective predecessor commands.